# Поиск по полю структуры/класса с++11/с++14

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11, c++14

Если у меня есть список/вектор объектов класса, как красиво сделать поиск по определенному полю класса. Нашел только [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/142632/) от 2012ого года. Наверняка сейчас стандартными средствами обойтись можно. Желательно c++11 версии. Так же интересно с реализацией в контейнерах QT, если они отличаются.
 
Пример задачи:

```
#include <list>
#include <QList>

class A {
public:
    A(a1, a2) : _a1(a1), _a2(a2) {}
    int a1() const;
    int a2() const;
private:
    int _a1 {0};
    int _a2 {0};
}

int main () {
    std::list<A> listA = getListA();
    QList<A> qListA = qGetListA();
    // как найти объект или индекс в списке на объект
    // у которого a2() возвращает значение 10?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке есть методы `std::find_if` и, `std::find_if_not`, позволяющие задать предикат на основе которого будет производиться поиск. `std::find_if` ищет первое вхождение элемента, для которого предикат вернет истину, `std::find_if_not` ищет первое вхождение элемента, для которого предикат вернет ложь.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::list<A> listA = getListA();
auto res = std::find_if(listA.begin(), listA.end(), 
                        [](const A & obj) { return obj.a2() == 10; });
if (res != listA.end())
{
    // Значение найдено, что-то с ним делаем
    // res в данном случае является итератором на элемент
}
```

Насколько я знаю, контейнеры в Qt поддерживают итераторы стандартной библиотеки с++, поэтому код для них будет абсолютно таким же. Однако я не готов гарантировать, что это будет работать во всех версиях Qt

Comment: В Qt работает find_if так же, как и со стандартной библиотекой.